# Почему картинка вставляется не как прозрачная

Tags: c++, windows, bmp, clipboard

У меня есть код, который создает прозрачную (по крайне мере должен) картинку (формат bmp), и сохраняет ее в буфер обмена. Однако при попытке вставить картинку в Photoshop/Gimp/Office - альфа канал игнорируется. Вот код:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Wingdi.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

pair<int, HGLOBAL> dibv5_img(void)
{
    const DWORD width = 100;
    const DWORD height = 100;
    BITMAPV5HEADER header = {0};
    header.bV5Size = sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER);
    header.bV5Width = width;
    header.bV5Height = -height;
    header.bV5Planes = 1;
    header.bV5BitCount = 32;
    header.bV5Compression = BI_BITFIELDS;
    header.bV5SizeImage = header.bV5Width * header.bV5Height * header.bV5BitCount / 8;
    header.bV5CSType = LCS_WINDOWS_COLOR_SPACE;
    header.bV5Intent = LCS_GM_IMAGES;

    header.bV5BlueMask = 0x000000FF;
    header.bV5GreenMask = 0x0000FF00;
    header.bV5RedMask = 0x00FF0000;
    header.bV5AlphaMask = 0xFF000000;

    DWORD masks[3];
    masks[0] = header.bV5BlueMask;
    masks[1] = header.bV5GreenMask;
    masks[2] = header.bV5RedMask;

    DWORD pixels[width * height];
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            pixels[i * width + j] = 0;
    for (DWORD i = height / 4; i < 3 * height / 4; ++i)
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            pixels[i * width + j] = (masks[0] | header.bV5AlphaMask) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

    HGLOBAL hmem = GlobalAlloc(GHND | GMEM_DDESHARE, header.bV5Size + sizeof(DWORD) * (3 + width * height));
    PVOID local_pointer = GlobalLock(hmem);

    memcpy(local_pointer, &header, sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER));
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(local_pointer) + sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER), masks, sizeof(DWORD) * 3);
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(local_pointer) + sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER) + sizeof(DWORD) * 3, pixels, 
        sizeof(DWORD) * width * height);
    GlobalUnlock(hmem);
    return pair<int, HGLOBAL>(CF_DIBV5, hmem);
}

int main(void)
{
    cout << sizeof(DWORD) << endl;
    if (!OpenClipboard(0))
        return 1;
    if (!EmptyClipboard())
        return 1;
    const auto data = dibv5_img();
    SetClipboardData(data.first, data.second);
    if (!CloseClipboard())
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Сама же картинка везде выглядит одинаково:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас же значение альфа-канала выставлено в FF, почему она должна быть прозрачной?

Comment: @Komdosh, ну если я не ошибаюсь, по задумке черного фона не должно быть - он прозрачный, поэтому я выставляю его в 0, а альфа канал синего прямоугольника выставляю в FF (не прозрачный)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CF_DIBV5` работает не со всеми приложениями. Нужно использовать `PNG` формат.

[Подробный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691001/6008532) с примером кода был дан на англоязычном StackOverflow.

Comment: Да, я видел данный ответ, но к сожалению там речь идет только о gimp/office. Буфер обмена photoshop не поддерживает png

Comment: В буфере обмена одновременно можно хранить данные в нескольких форматах, в том ответе есть код программы, который показывает, что лежит в буфере обмена. Просто соберите её и проверьте, какие форматы используют необходимые программы. А потом уже реализуйте своё сохранение.

Comment: я уже проверил, photoshop экспортирует много своих внутренних форматов + те же bitmap'ы, поэтому найти среди используемых форматов нужный не получится - стандартные уже я использовал. Задал аналогичный вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587014/why-is-bmp-created-as-not-transparent - получил те же ответы

Comment: Похоже, что Adobe, как обычно, решили пойти своим путём. Если поддержка Photoshop Действительна важна, я бы попробовал посмотреть, что там за данные, может там какой PSD есть. Правда писать свой конвертер в PSD это тоже не самая простая задача, но там хотя бы документация есть: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

Comment: Интересная мысль. из адобовских форматов нашел такие: Photoshop Paste in Place
Photoshop DIB Layer
Photoshop DIB Layer X
Photoshop Clip Source
Adobe Photoshop Image, интересно какой из них psd